# Pass command's stderr from a build task into Azure DevOps

Tags: build, azure-devops, stderr

I have a VSTS (Azure DevOps) build which contains a *PowerShell* or a *Command line* task. This task is running some program: `program.exe`. When `program.exe` returns a non-zero exit code, the build is failed as expected. `program.exe` also prints a detailed error message to the `stderr` stream in case of an error.

The problem is that the content of the `stderr` stream is not passed to the build. The task is always returning the following error message which is also displayed as a build failure message on the build summary tab:

> Process completed with exit code 1.

Which is useless. The user has to look for a failed task, open its output and search for an error message there. That's not very convenient.

How to easily pass the content of `stderr` to the build?

Do I have to manually capture `stderr` and then send it to the build using PowerShell or is there a setting to change the build behaviour to work as I expect?

Answer (score 3):

I just added "`2>&1 | Write-Host`" to the command so that the stderr stream will be routed to the Write-Host stream. Reference this thread: *[VSTS build fails with "Process completed with exit code 0 and had 3 error(s) written to the error stream." even though I set my PowerShell script to ignore errors](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/86161/view.html)*

You can also try uncheck the `Fail on Standard Error` in your PowerShell script configuration and write the lastexitcode to pass the task:

[image]

> **Fail on Standard Error**
>
> If this is true, this task will fail if any errors are written to the
>   error pipeline, or if any data is written to the Standard Error
>   stream. Otherwise the task will rely solely on $LASTEXITCODE and the
>   exit code to determine failure.

Then you can output the error or warning by using PowerShell or VSTS task commands.

```
Write-Warning “warning”
Write-Error “error”
Write-Host " ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]this is the waring"
Write-Host " ##vso[task.logissue type=error;sourcepath=consoleapp/main.cs;linenumber=1;columnnumber=1;code=100;]this is an error "
```

More information about the VSTS task command, you can refer to: [Logging Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell)

Comment: Thank you but It's still not ideal since every line from the `stderr` stream is considered a single error and still it adds another error at the end which is "PowerShell exited with code '1'".

Comment: Where do I find the PowerShell script configuration

Comment: @KarlMorrison if you have the yaml for the pipeline, `failOnStderr` can be passed as an argument to the `powershell` task. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)

Comment: The first link is not accessible.